# how to convert sql procedure to MySQL syntax from sql-server, can anyone suggest me about this

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `intranet`.`test1`()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    @out_desc AS VARCHAR(1000),
    @out_mesg AS VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @email AS NVARCHAR(50),
    @first_name AS VARCHAR(50),
    @body AS NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @birth_date AS DATETIME;

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY;
    FOR
    SELECT first_name, birth_date, email
    FROM emp_master;
    OPEN C1
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
    @first_name, @birth_date, @email
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF DATEPART(DAY,@birth_date) = DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())
        AND DATEPART(MONTH,@birth_date) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
        BEGIN
            SET @body = '<b>Happy Birthday ' + @first_name +
            '</b><br />Many happy returns of the day'
            + '<br /><br />Customer Relationship Department'
            EXEC sp_send_mail
            'pradeep.y@csmsoftware.com',
            @email,
            'Birthday Wishes',
            @body,
            'htmlbody',
            @output_mesg = @out_mesg output,
            @output_desc = @out_desc output
            PRINT @out_mesg
            PRINT @out_desc
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
        @first_name, @birth_date, @email
    END
    CLOSE C1;
    DEALLOCATE C1;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The only way to reliably convert a stored proc is to completely rewrite it in MySQL. However, MySQL cannot send emails from sql code, unless you write / find a compiled user defined function that takes care of sending emails.

Comment: i am getting some basic syntax error while running it in mysql server

Comment: can u suggest me about it\

Comment: Syntax error - no surprise at all... When it comes to stored procedures most dbms products have their own incompatible versions.

Comment: actually i wanted to send an email to the employees in the company for their birthday wishes and i am not getting any method to send an email using mysql, can u please suggest me about it

Comment: SO is about providing help, not doing your work for you. And as I pointed out in the edited first comment: MySQL cannot send emails from sql code, unless you write / find a compiled user defined function that takes care of sending emails. Probably it is easier to write a script that can send emails and retrieves the data from the database, rather than trying to send an email from MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, is there any other way to send an email in mysql

Comment: No, there is not.